# Percentages with SASS - one pixel problems?

Tags: css, sass

I want to build my minimal CSS framework. I did a grid system in SASS:

```
$width: 960px;
width: $width;

.grid-12 { width: $width; }
.grid-11 { width: percentage((($width/12)*11)/$width) }
.grid-10 { width: percentage((($width/12)*10)/$width) }
.grid-9 { width: percentage((($width/12)*9)/$width) }
.grid-8 { width: percentage((($width/12)*8)/$width) }
.grid-7 { width: percentage((($width/12)*7)/$width) }
.grid-6 { width: percentage(($width/2)/$width) }
.grid-5 { width: percentage((($width/12)*5)/$width) }
.grid-4 { width: percentage(($width/3)/$width) }
.grid-3 { width: percentage(($width/4)/$width) }
.grid-2 { width: percentage(($width/6)/$width) }
.grid-1 { width: percentage(($width/12)/$width) }
```

It works great, but sometimes - in some resolutions, eg. at my mobile with landscape view (960x540) some elements are 1px too short. It happens also when I resize browser.

What can I do?

Comment: `some elements are 1px too short` shorter than what?

Comment: What can you do?  um, accept that mathematics dictates that not every number will be evenly divisible by 12?  design your page differently so it won't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "fix" for this. That's the way it is with all responsive layouts and grid systems. There are techniques like [float isolation](http://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret) that can help keep your rounding errors from multiplying. Otherwise, 10 `1px` errors can turn into a `10px` error. I wouldn't use that everywhere, but it's useful if you have a gallery-style layout with a lot of elements, all the same size, floating next to each other.

The real solution, mentioned in a comment above, is to adjust your design so that `1px` rounding  errors don't matter. If `1px` can ruin your layout, responsive design isn't going to work.

You can't eliminate the rounding errors, but you have some control over *where* the missing pixels should go. By floating things left or right, and nesting in different ways, you can move the rounding errors where they will be least noticeable. Another solution is to apply `layout` (instead of `float`/`width`) to the last element in a row, and it will expand to fill the remaining space. The easiest way to apply layout is with `overflow: hidden;`, but that has some drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

some of the calculations will result in a number that can NOT be divided by 2

sometimes you will get .5px ...

and because of this . you will sometimes have 1 extra pixel

Comment: I know that :) The problem is - how can I do something about it:)

Comment: dont divide by 11/9/7/5 .. choose something that gets the math right :)

Comment: go for even numbers .. everything in computer works better with even numbers :)

Comment: I want it responsive, so percents ;) Even numbers may be a problem here :)